# What molecule is this. Pretty sure its not ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, molecules, structural-formula, identification

This is the molecule in question
This in advance. [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Humulene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humulene) is a compound found in aromatic plants, which has insect-repellent properties in such plants. Currently it is also being researched as an anti-inflammatory agent.

Answer (score 6):

The compound of the structure on the cup is [humulene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humulene), which is naturally occuring sesquiterpene (three isoprene units) isolated from the cones of *Humulus lupulus* (hops), thus its name:

[image: Humulene]

Although Oscar Lanzi gave the brief description good enough to identify the compound, my intention to give extended answer is to clarify the OP's comment of "pretty sure its not ethanol." I believe OP made the comment because the structure is on the cup from a brewing company. The reason the structure to be on the cup is humulene and its reaction products in the brewing process of beer are known to  give many beers their “hoppy” aroma ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humulene) and [The essemtial oil of Hops](http://realbeer.com/hops/aroma.html)). The company described it as "[...] juicy hop forward beers brewed with a New England yeast strain with lots of flaked oats, barley, and wheat, and generous late and dry **hopping**"! The company's symbol says its all: It is a cone of the Hop plant.

Comment: I'm no organic chemist but why is the green circle an isoprene, the others have two carbons at one end and one at the other?

Comment: @ porphyrin: Regardless of where is the double bond, isoprene unit is 2-methylbutene or 2-methylbutane. The place of double bond(s) depends on the biochemical process during the biosynthesis. For example, see how many monoterpenes $(\ce{C_{10}})$ in literature.

Comment: @ porphyrin: Two units in blue and red are traditional head-to-tail attachment but one in green is not, again, due to relavent biosysnthesis.